# How did words like rubbish, ribbon and cabbage get "BB"?

Tags: orthography, consonants, contemporary-english

Certain words that have double B in Modern English didn't have "BB" in the word they are derived from.

- **Rubbish:** "c. 1400, *ro**b**ous*, from Anglo-French *ru**b**ouses*" ([Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=rubbish))
- **Ribbon:** "early 14c., *ri**b**ane*, from Old French *ri**b**an* "a ribbon," variant of *ru**b**an* (13c.)" ([Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/word/ribbon))
- **Cabbage:** "mid-15c., *ca**b**oge*, from Old North French *ca**b**oche* "head" ... , from Old French *ca**b**oce* "head," " ([Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=cabbage))

They did not have a second B before but they do in Modern English.

In contrast,

- **Bubble:** "early 14c., perhaps from Middle Dutch *bo**bb**el* (n.) and/or Middle Low German *bu**bb**eln* (v.)" ([Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=bubble))
- **Babble:** "mid-14c., "to speak as an infant speaks," frequentative of *bla**bb**en*, of echoic origin (compare Old Norse *bla**bb**ra*, Danish *bla**bb**re* "babble," German plappern "to babble")." ([Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=blabber))

Is the addition of a second B in Modern English (or Middle English) random? Why and how did some of those words acquire a second B?

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is: maybe there was a sound change that shortened the vowel before the *B* and then the second B was added to reflect the change in spelling?? (Vowels before double consonants are usually short.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spelling *bb* in *rubbish, ribbon, cabbage* is not entirely random because it is related to their pronunciations, as Decapitated Soul noted in the comments. The occurrence of a double consonant digraph such as *bb* is generally restricted in English to the position after a "short vowel" sound /æ, ɛ, ɪ, ɒ, ʌ/ or /ʊ/ (/ʊ/ is rare so I don't think any words actually exist with it before *-bb-*).

However, the double-consonant spelling pattern was not applied to all words with pronunciations of this type, as there are words like *trouble, double, public, publish, robin* whose standard present-day spellings do not have *bb*. Some words of French origin with short vowels were spelled with double consonant digraphs, while others were not; the reasons for this do appear to be fairly random. The Oxford English Dictionary notes old spellings with *-bb-* exist for *double* and *robbin.*

The pronunciations with a short vowel aren't completely straightforward to explain, but do seem to follow a general pattern. In English words from Anglo-Norman/Old French, it is fairly common for vowels in non-final syllables that were originally unstressed in French to be pronounced as short. Other examples are *courage, savage, punish, lemon.* However, there are also words where a long vowel developed in a similar context (*bacon, label*). For more detailed coverage of how the pronunciation of words like this developed, you can look at Otto Jespersen's *Modern English Grammar on Historical Principles*.